# Batch File: Getting user input during execution of other commands, then checking it later

Tags: windows, batch-file, input, user-input

What I want is a command (or series of commands) that works with Windows 7, 8.1, and 10. It needs to collect user input at any time during the execution of the batch file it's in, only to checked and interpreted later. I do not mind using an input text file.

I've already searched for an answer, but the closest I've come to it is `<nul set /p "input="`, but it requires the user to press a key and hit enter at the exact moment the command is run. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you want a bat file that can be processing things and accept input at any time?  For instance, a bat file that loops through files on your hard drive constantly and at any point the user could type in a filter or something similar?

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: So an input file will be the easiest way to go and will only work if your bat file is based on a loop.  If it's doing any long-running tasks you will not be able to check input during.  Basically, if you have a loop, you just make checking the text file part of the loop.  There may be other tricks that I'm not aware of, but I doubt it.  I'll try to whip up a quick example of the input file/loop concept.

Comment: The same question restated yet again. If it feels like you are pushing something up hill, then you ARE. Choose the correct technology. You are essentially asking "_why doesn't my solution to an unknown problem work_?". For all your questions the answer is you are using a wrong approach, but with two batch files you can simulate it in an ugly way.

Comment: @Noodles We don't know his requirements and besides, you don't learn anything from doing something right. :)

Comment: Although I do have to say that I just looked at the other question and it was worded much better :)

Comment: It needs a single threaded pattern as Win 16. You break tasks up into small units. All inbuilt commands only work while active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method utilizes `GOTO` to create a loop which checks the first line of `input.txt` every 6 seconds or so.  You could replace the content of `:DOSTUFF` with anything you want.  Let me know if you have questions.

```
@echo off
GOTO DOSTUFF

:CHECKINPUT
    for /f %%a in (input.txt) do (
        if %%a NEQ "" (
            set "input=%%a"
            GOTO GOTINPUT
            )
        exit /b
    )
    GOTO DOSTUFF

:GOTINPUT
    echo Thanks for the input!
    echo Here is what you entered:
    echo %input%
    GOTO ENDER
:DOSTUFF
    echo I could be doing other things here, but instead I'm just waiting for input...
    PING 127.0.0.1 -n 6 >nul
    GOTO CHECKINPUT
:ENDER
    pause
```

While this was running in one window, I just ran `echo test>input.txt` in another command prompt.

To make this more robust you might want to overwrite the file after you check it.  This can easily be done with `echo.>input.txt`