# How do I stop a loop by clicking the enter key in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that, at a certain point, runs a loop of random numbers:

```
:rand1matrix
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%
goto rand1matrix
```

I want someone to be able to click the enter key and stop the loop, like

```
:rand1matrix
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%
pause
goto rand1matrix
```

I just don't want the loop to stop and ask for someone to click enter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36775423/batch-file-getting-user-input-during-execution-of-other-commands-then-checking this help? might work creating a loop to constantly check for user input

Comment: `>nul timeout /T 1` instead of `pause`?

Comment: What do you mean by "stop the loop"? Do you want to terminate it, or do you want to halt it for a certain amount of time or until another key press?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is start another batch in another process that will create a temporary file when the user presses a key. In your loop you can then poll the existence of the file:

```
set pollfile=some_random_name.poll.tmp
IF EXIST "%pollfile%" del "%pollfile%"

start cmd /c stoploop.bat %pollfile%

:loop
IF EXIST "%pollfile%" goto :exitloop
:: DO WHAT YOU WANT
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%
goto :loop

:exitloop
echo We got out of the loop :)
IF EXIST "%pollfile%" del "%pollfile%"
```

`stoploop.bat` can be something like this:

```
@echo off

pause > nul
type nul > "%~1"

exit /b 0
```

Pressing any key will then let the `stoploop.bat` create an empty file to the location given as argument.
In your main batch script you just have to check each time if the file given as argument to the `stoploop.bat` already exists.
You can set `pollfile` to whatever filename/path you like. Just be carefull and don't use the name or path to a file you don't want to delete.

Normally letting the two batch-scripts share the same window with `start /b` should work (it worked for me). If it doesn't (or you absolutely want the user to use another window to stop the loop) you can start the `stoploop.bat` in another window with `start cmd /c stoploop.bat %pollfile%` intstead of the `start /b`.

If you want it to work only for the `enter` key and not for any key, you can replace `pause > nul` with `set /p =`.